# Source that a woman is considered to have a bris milah

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, brit-milah

I recall learning, I think in mesechtas kiddushin, that a woman is the (halachic?) equivalent of a man who has had a bris milah performed. In other words, since she does not have the same organ she is viewed as if she is a person who has had a bris performed, not as a person who does not have a need to have one performed. What is the source for this idea?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's the nafka mina?

Comment: LeMai Nafka Minah?

Comment: for a dvar torah i'm working on, no halachic implication (that i'm aware of)

Comment: @yoel, SethJ a practical application is mentioned in the _g'mara_ (see my answer): this is the reason a woman can do a _mila_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[*Bavli*, *Avoda Zara* 27:1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4029):

> אשה כמאן דמהילא דמיא
>   a woman is like someone circumcised

Comment: Spins on this come up in other contexts, e.g. suppose a non-Jewish man had his genitalia amputated, hence circumcision is an impossibility; can he convert to Judaism?

Comment: @Shalom, this question probably covers that http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33388/what-happens-when-a-potential-convert-cant-have-a-circumcision