# PTIJ: Remy the rat converting to Judaism

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

How does Remy, a rat from [Ratatouille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratatouille_(film)), ever perform proper Tevilah to become Jewish, if there's a concept that one cannot hold a rodent/Sheretz and become Tahor in a Mikveh?

(All the while under the notion that living beings "hold" themselves.)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: There's no rule that everyone must be able to convert https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/33402/759

Comment: I recommend that you add in that a living being holds itself, because otherwise we must say that he's not holding himself, thus he's not holding a sheretz and therefore all is well.

Answer (score 4):

A Sheretz is only mitamei when it's dead.

Comment: It wouldn't be able to survive too long in the water, tho.

Comment: That's a seperate issue. Wasn't part of the question.

Comment: Need to work this totally-correct answer into some Purim Torah, presumably something to do with the scene near the beginning of the movie with the rat poison.